# Estimate of smooth integers doesn't fit the actual graph

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I was studying smooth integers, that is integers that have only small prime factors. Denoting
by $P^+(n)$ the largest prime factor of $n$, we define $\Psi(x,B):=|\{ n \le x:\,P^+(n) \le B\}|$ as being the function that counts the amount of integers smaller than $x$ such that every prime factor is $\le B$. Wikipedia has the following estimate for $\Psi(x,B)$:
$$\Psi(x,B) \sim \frac{1}{\pi(B)!} \prod_{p\le B} \frac{\log x}{\log p}$$
where $\pi(B)$ denotes the number of primes less than or equal to $B$. I tried to plot an example of it, first plotting $\Psi(x, 5)$ for all positive integers $x < 100$, and then plotting the estimate 1/(3!) * (log x)^3 / (log 2 * log 3 * log 5) on the same interval, but the graphs didn't match at all:[image]

So I guess I have made a mistake somewhere, but I have no idea where. Why does the estimate deviate so much from the actual plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ratio between the two gets better for much larger numbers.  Here is the ratio between $\Psi(x,5)$ and the approximation as $x$ goes from 10 to about half a million
[image]

Comment: So the limit of the ratio is 1 but only for huge numbers?

Comment: I guess so.  It is the number of integer points (m,n,p) with $2^m3^n5^p\lt N$, or equivalently $m\log2+n\log3+p\log5<\log N$, and the estimate is the volume bounded by that plane and the three axes.